# SSMS importing data (using Excel) error: SSMS reads that my field has 255 characters but I have less

Tags: sql-server, excel

I'm importing data using Excel as the data source (97 - 2003) and this error shows up:

[image]

[image]

My Excel data has a length of 9 only. [Here's a sample file I uploaded in Github](https://github.com/crln-blue/publicdocx/blob/main/TO%20SQL%20SERVER%20-%20Master%20Data%20Tables%20to%20SSMS.xls).

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: When dealing with Excel files, you can't choose the data types of the source; the JET/ACE drivers are  ̶s̶t̶u̶p̶i̶d̶  kind enough to infer the data types and lengths (in)correctly for you; how kind! Unless I recall incorrect, JET *used* to assume that all columns were 255 characters in length if they were textual; whether they could be longer on not. (Side question, why are you still using an XLS file?)

Comment: Hello @Larnu, thanks for the insight! I only tried uploading using 97-2003 excel file type because I can't find the latest version of Excel in the SQL Server Import and Export Wizard. I thought I should match the excel type to the version selected in the dialog box. I'm currently using the latest version in Excel and I'm not sure if it will work if I choose the 2016 version in the dialog box.

Edit: okay, I tried importing a XLSX document and I picked 2016 but I get this error: 
The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0' provider is not registered on the local machine. (System.Data)